# Meteor.com operations getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: meteor

All the standard meteor operations are all of the sudden returning errors after updating my database uri. Deploy, logout, and login all return errors. I have checked meteor.com status page and it claims all is operational. I have tried changing even my database to its old url, and deleting my instance entirely from galaxy, but I still receive these errors. Any one have any idea how to fix this? I am not using any proxy.

logout/login

> stream error Network error: wss://www.meteor.com/auth/websocket:
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.meteor.com www.meteor.com:443

Deploy

> Connection error (getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND galaxy.meteor.com
>   galaxy.meteor.com:443)

Answer (score 0):

The server is down causing these errors, the galaxy status page is unreliable for server status.